# iAd Banner stretch's screen and interupt's gameplay

Tags: ios, iphone, iad

In my app I have iAd enabled in three of my scenes and in one of the scenes I want to disable the ads because of the screen being stretched when they pop up. In ViewController.m I enable the ads like so...

```
 self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

and I want to disable the ad when the user clicks the play button which takes them to the gameplay scene.(Gameplay scene ads have to be disabled) How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I am getting from your question there could be a couple of ways to do it. You can check if the view controller is displaying an iAd first with

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter=isDisplayingBannerAd) BOOL displayingBannerAd;
```

A boolean value that indicates whether the view controller is displaying an iAd banner.

If so then cancel it with this method

```
- (void)cancelBannerViewAction
```

Our inside of the IBAction Method of the play button just change `self.canDisplayBannerAds = NO;`
and self being the ViewController that is currently being displayed.